# Attention mechanism on sequences of state vectors of different sizes?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I am working with multivariate time series of multiple patients and want to implement this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05010.pdf)

It proposes a bidirectional LSTM with an attention mechanism. Basically, after each new "time input" for a patient, we keep track of the state vector, represented by node h in the schema below, and then link them all (in the neural network sense) to multiple reading heads.

The paper isn't too long, but I will try to add the most relevant parts as images below. Hopefully it will be enough for an experienced person to understand what I'm trying to do

[image]

[image]

Even though I'm pretty new at tensorflow (which is what I have to implement this with, since it will sit on top of existing tensorflow code), I can kind of see how that would work code wise. I'm not sure there are a preexisting high level functions to do this but it should still be doable. However, I have some question on the more theoretical side of things.

As far as I understand, T is variable across patients. I understand the logic, but how would I go about implementing this? Do I have to set some max_T corresponding to the longest time series seen in my dataset, create that many h nodes (state vectors) and fill every unobserved state vector for patients who have less than max_T observations with 0's? Would the extra nodes full of 0s harm the implementation?

I know neural nets can typically handle input of different length, but I'm not sure whether this applies here.